# How to publish MS Access 2010 table using SharePoint 2010 UserInfo table back to SharePoint Access Services?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 Task list which includes an "Assigned To" column of type "Person or Group".  I then opened this in Access 2010 using SharePoint's "Actions" menu.  At this point I used Access 2010's Report Wizard to build a nice report that shows tasks grouped the way that the client requested.  Everything's beautiful to this point...

Now I'm trying to publish this back to the SharePoint server using "Publish to Access Services" from within Access.  However, the "Run Compatibility Checker" phase stops me with a ACCWeb107006 Error: Table or query name is a reserved name and incompatible with the Web.  The table in question is "UserInfo".  If I generate the report without using this table, I get a number instead of a name for the "Assigned To" column, so that's a no-go.

How do I get past this?  I've been searching and trying for 2 straight days now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all sites by default ALWAYS have a table called UserInfo.

I mean, if you just going to create your own table, then just re-name the table and publish and you done in 10 seconds. So the issue here is I assume that you want to use the UserTable from the SharePoint site?

Keep in mind that all sites have that "userTable" by default. So, delete your local user table.  You may very well have to delete your reports + queries based on that UserTable since they don't exist and you will NOT be able to publish those objects (so make a copy of your application, and then remove the reports + query with user table - you might not have to do this, but suspect you will).

Now, publish your application.

Next step is to simply now link in the user table.

You can "add" the user table back by linking to the site that Access just created by publishing your application.

On the ribbon External data, and then choose (usually from the dropdown called "more"), simply choose SharePoint list. When the link wizard starts, enter the SAME url of the web site you just published (you can cut + past that URL from backstage if you like me and don't like to type).

Now, in the list of available tables (lists), you will see the user table as a choice. Link it in

Now you can build your reports + queries etc. with that user table included. (just import the queries and reports in the above copy you made as I mentioned if you did have to delete them).

So, you cannot publish with a local copy of that UserTable. But, after you publish, you can link in the user table and then design + use that table from that point on in your application.

And as noted,  if you have some reports + queries in the un-published app, then you may very well have to remove them before you able to publish (the compatibility checker will possbile complain).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this Monday and let you know, but it certainly sounds like it's going in the right direction.  Connecting to an external table was the connection my brain wasn't making.

Comment: Published web applications allow external links to even a local accDB file or SQL server. It only from a web browser must you use tables and data from the published site in a web browser. Keep in mind that the client version of the application allows consuming data from many different kinds of data sources. You can thus link to and consume data from outside of the published site. For web the "one exception" of external data is the user table and this is really much due to the fact that after you publish all sites have that "user" table added for you. So publish, and then link in the user table